# VGA Splitter Switch?

Tags: projector, cable, output

I'm looking for switches that can take two VGA inputs, and an audio input from each, and switch between them to one VGA+audio output. Basically, I want to be able to go from one input to another without messing around with cables on the output itself; I just want to be able to flip a switch and be done with it. Somehow, I haven't found a lot of products online that do this. Any recommendations?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify keyboard, but sometimes it can be useful to switch USB along with the VGA signal. For this you'd want a [KVM](http://www.cablestogo.com/category/vga/vga-kvm-supplies/vga-kvm-switches).

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a simple VGA switch.  For example:

[http://www.amazon.com/MT-VIKI-VGA-Splitter-Amplifier-MT-15-2AV/dp/B00DRGDDX0/ref=sr_1_7?s=electronics&ie=UTF8&qid=1407127908&sr=1-7&keywords=2-port+vga+switch](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00DRGDDX0)